Azure DevOps Service Principal details in DevOps pipeline not working (anymore)
I used to be able to use the service principal for AZ CLI or PWSH tasks in my DevOps pipeline, but have been banging my head against the wall since yesterday because I can't get it to work anymore. Has something changed, or do I overlook something?
After reading this post I replicated the setup in my own pipeline, but the 'servicePrincipalKey' is empty.
The code I'm using in my pipeline is:
- task: AzureCLI@2
    displayName: 'Get Azure CLI credentials'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: $(serviceConnection)
      scriptType: 'pscore'
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      addSpnToEnvironment: true
      useGlobalConfig: true
      inlineScript: |
        $InformationPreference = "Continue"
        Write-Information "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CLIENT_ID]$env:servicePrincipalId" | Out-Null
        Write-Information "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CLIENT_SECRET]$env:servicePrincipalKey" | Out-Null
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($env:servicePrincipalKey)) {
          Write-Warning "Service principal key is empty"
        }
        elseif ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($env:servicePrincipalId)) {
          Write-Warning "Service principal id is empty"
        }
        else {
          Write-Output "Service principal id and key are set"
        }

  - task: Powershell@2
    displayName: Output SPN
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      script: |
        Write-Host "CLIENT_ID: '$env:CLIENT_ID')"
        Write-Host "CLIENT_SECRET: '$env:CLIENT_SECRET'"

The results are:
AzureCLI@2 task:

WARNING: Service principal key is empty

Powershell@2 task:

CLIENT_ID: '***')

CLIENT_SECRET: ''

Any thoughts?

I just realized that my ADO service connection has recently been switched to 'workload identity federation' (WIF). I should be using 'idToken' instead.

This is helpful, but could you provide a more complete answer? Like how did you use it? Was it a literal replacement for the Key or did it also eliminate the need for the Id?
